# facebook java integration

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I followed http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication and got the access_token of a user. Now, I want to post some text/images onto his wall from a java application.

How can I use this access_token to publish onto user's wall?

I could not find any suitable documentation for desktop applications.

--
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [restfb](http://restfb.com/) - a Java API for both the Graph API and the old rest API.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have applied for the access token with the publish_stream permission.If so you can easily post images or messages or links to the users wall using restfb. There are a lot of sample codes available in the restFb website.